# Nuancier des grossièretés

Tags: usage, grossieretes

N'étant pas de langue maternelle française, une des choses qui m'est très difficile est de 'sentir' la force de certains mots, même si j'en connais la signification et l'utilisation.

De plus, c'est quelque chose de relativement subjectif : comme me retorquait un vieux marin breton quand j'ai dit avoir compris que "ça ne se disait pas" :

> Eh ben, en France, même si ça se dit pas, on le dit.

Donc, à niveau social et contexte égal, comment se comparent (par exemple) :

- Shit/merde
- Fuck (and derivatives) / Foutre (et dérivés)
- Je m'en fiche/Je m'en fous

*J'ai l'impression que "Je m'en fous" (par exemple) est moins 'fort' que "Va te faire foutre". Juste ou pas?*

**Edit**

J'en ai pensé à d'autres depuis (*putain*, *enculé*, *enfoiré*, *bordel*, *conneries*), est-ce qu'on les ajoute ici et on en fait une question canonique (c'est vrai que la liste potentielle est relativement longue...)? J'aurais bien voulu pouvoir trier par ordre de grossièreté, avec en face des équivalents (en force) anglais. Qu'en pensez-vous?

Comment: Je pense qu'il est important de noter que les variations dans ce domaine sont très importantes d'un pays à l'autre. En particulier, les français et les québécois sont choqués par des choses très différentes.

Comment: "Va te faire faire" (qu'on pourrait traduire par "go to hell" ou "go fuck yourself") n'a pas le même sens que "je m'en fous" ("I don't care").  La première expression est adressée à une tierce personne tandis que la deuxième fait référence à soi-même.

Comment: Je ne suis pas tenté par une liste canonique de gros mots. Quant à leur force, elle varie pas mal avec le contexte, le locuteur et l’intonation que ce soit en français ou en anglais; alors faire une correspondance entre les deux me semble assez illusoire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Merde* est beaucoup moins fort que "shit". Le mot anglais le plus proche de *merde* me semble être "crap". J'ai souvent vu des petits enfants francophones dire *merde* en public sans que leurs parents réagissent, ce qui ne serait pas le cas d'un petit anglophone qui dirait "shit" !

Je ne crois pas que l'on puisse traduire "fuck" par *foutre*, à part dans quelques cas précis. Le mot qui correspondraît le mieux à "fuck" me semble être "baiser". En tout cas, *foutre* est, la plupart du temps beaucoup moins impoli que "fuck". Mais on peut constater un très large écart de gravité entre, par exemple, *je m'en fous* (expression familière mais pas vraiment vulgaire) et *va te faire foutre* (ce qui est carrément une insulte). Je dois signaler que la même sorte d'écart existe en anglais entre, par exemple, [this is fucking brilliant](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COlPQlNguvU) et "go fuck yourself!"

*Je m'en fiche* est moins familier que *je m'en fous*, mais il ne faut quand même pas le dire dans un contexte formel.

A souligner : moi non plus, je ne suis pas francophone, et je ne suis pas certain de ce que je dis ici. Si j'ai dis des bêtises [*], j'espère qu'un francophone me reprendra :)

<sub>[*]Mot qui est, bien sûr, moins familier que *conneries* :)</sub>

Comment: Peut-être qu'il faut ajouter *putain* dans le mélange... ce qui peut remplacer *fucking* dans certains circonstances...

Comment: *putain* est beaucoup plus proche de *fucking* comme explétif multi-fonction ("putain de" etc.)

Comment: En tout cas, c'est la traduction choisie pour le dialogue du début de _Quatre mariages et un enterrement_.

Answer (score 7):

C'est effectivement très varié.  Un « putain » n'a pas la même force dans la bouche de mon collègue marseillais (pour qui c'est l'équivalent d'un « enfin... » chez Gaston) qu'il aurait dans celle de ma mère (je n'ai pas le souvenir qu'il en soit jamais sorti devant moi).

Au contraire de Vincent, je ne perçois pas de plus de différence de force entre « shit » et « merde » qu'il n'y a de variation dans la force et l'usage à l'intérieur d'une même langue.

« Foutre » est par contre moins fort que « fuck » (mais j'ai l'impression que « fuck » suit la même voie que « foutre » avec simplement du retard).

Je ne sais pas si j'ai raison, mais je perçois « fiche » comme une forme « polie » de « foutre » (comme dans les couples purée-putain, miel-merde) qui a mieux réussi que les autres.

Effectivement, « Je m'en fous » est moins fort que « Va te faire foutre ! » pour commencer l'allusion sexuelle est, pour moi, toujours perceptible dans le second cas.

Answer (score 6):

Si un mot est marqué comme [trivial](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/foutre) ou vulgaire, c'est déjà un bon signe qu'il risque de choquer certains.

En soi, ça ne répond sans doute pas à ta question, mais je pense que dans le doute, mieux vaux éviter d'utiliser ce genre de mots en présence d'inconnus; de la même manière qu'on commencerait par vouvoyer quelqu'un qu'on ne connaît pas.

Dans un cadre plus familial, une relâchement est possible, mais il appartient à chacun de sentir quels mots sont plus ou moins admissibles dans quels cercles. (Par exemple, il serait sans doute très mal vu de te répondre *Je t'en foutrai, moi, des questions sur la grossièreté!*)

Pour déterminer la gravité, on peut aussi considérer le reste de la phrase: s'il vise directement l'interlocuteur, il risque forcément de choquer plus, de la même manière que *Tais-toi!* est plus blessant que *Je me tais.*